# Set the order of multiple screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, login-screen, 19.10

Is there a standard way to set the order of multiple screens in Ubuntu 19.10?

I have used the "right click on the desktop" > "Display Settings" to set the order of my 3 screens. It works well after login to the system. But before the login the order is different to this setting here. Hence, my login window is not on the center screen and rather in my case on the right screen.

Is there a way to apply the same screen settings of the desktop to the screen settings of the login?

Answer (score 0):

I do this with a script using

```
xrandr --output eDP  --auto --output HDMI-A-0 --primary --left-of eDP
```

here HDMI-A-0 us set as primary and to the left of the secondary screen eDP

I get the monitor names from

```
xrandr
```

add that to startup applications (power key, startup, add ) and if that doesnt work, make it a script and add it in startup applications

```
bash "wherever/whatever/whatisname.sh"
```

you could also do a keyboard shortcut to that script for manual monitor placement.

and you will need to set the third monitor to the left (or right) of another monitor. if that works, join above xrandr command with && for the second placement.

Comment: guessing that you could add the third monitor onto the single line there  like adding 

--output HDMI-A-2 --auto --right-of HDMI-A-0

though I have not tried it myself with 3 monitors